# How to implement Server Sent Events in MVC3 using .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pushviewcontroller, server-sent-events

I want to make a feed application using SSE in MVC .NET. I was looking over the web but I can't find an example or a way to implement the SSE in MVC. I developed a very dirty solution where a View calls a Controller that calls a second View, and this 2nd View makes the push to the first one. I hope that somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). It is very easy to set up and get running, and there are plenty of examples in ASP.NET to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If ASP.NET WebApi is an option you can checkout my library, ServerSentEvents4Net. The code is up on [Github](https://github.com/erizet/ServerSentEvent4Net), and its also available on [Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/ServerSentEvent4Net).

Comment: How do you avoid blocking ASP threads for each connected client? As I understand it, the server must keep the response open for each client. Some bad examples I have seen use an infinite loop in the controller action, but that will never work. I just wondered how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to implement [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) in [mvc4](/questions/tagged/mvc4) using [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) (it should work fine for `MVC3` also)
**Controller part:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "SSE WITH ASP.NET MVC";
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Message()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/event-stream");

        }
```

**View Part:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function contentLoaded() {
                var source = new EventSource('home/message');
                //var ul = $("#messages");
                source.onmessage = function (e) {

                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    var returnedItem = e.data;
                    li.textContent = returnedItem;
                    $("#messages").append(li);
                }
            };

            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false);
        </script>
        <h2><%: ViewBag.Message%></h2>
        <p>
            SSE WITH ASP.NET MVC
        </p>
        <ul id="messages">
        </ul>
```

**Output:**

[image]